# Partially include a file

Tags: php

I am using `include_once` to include a file containing variables I need (defined by `define();`) but I cannot change the file itself.

At the end of this file it also uses an `include_once` to call a file with lots of serverside operations. As my script is run locally, I am getting a bunch of errors. When commented out, it works fine.

I am thinking of cloning the file, removing the offending include, including it, reading the variables and finally deleting it. Seems a little awkward though.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: You could create an empty file that is named as the second include_once's  (the one with the serverside operations) and include_once it in your code ...

Comment: @Marc before the other include_once? Interesting idea. Why not post it as an answer

Comment: Because there are probably (hopefully) way better ways to solve this

Comment: The core of this problem is, that in the same file you have declarative code (definition of global constants), and active code (include of script that executes server operations) - this has to be split in two scripts. Your current problem is minor compared to what can happen in production if you leave it like this.

Answer (score 0):

It`s always a good practice, to hold variables (used globaly) separately. So create for example: defines.php and put it there. Include it in all files where You need it. Simple